# Can this optimized barrel shifter be made arithmetic?

Tags: shift-register

Every schematic I've seen for a barrel shifter looks as such:

```
bit  3   2   1   0
     |  -|  -|  -| 0
     | | | | | | | |
     MUX MUX MUX MUX--Select bit 0 (To all stage-1 MUX)
     |  -|---+   |
     | | |  -|---+
     | | | | |  -|-+---0
     | | | | | | | |
     MUX MUX MUX MUX--Select bit 1 (To all stage-2 MUX)
     |   |   |   |
     |  -|-+-|-+-|-+---0
     | | | | | | | |
     MUX MUX MUX MUX--Select bit 2 (To all stage-3 MUX)
      |   |   |   |
```

Instead, I came up with this:

```
bit  4   3   2   1
     |  -|  -|  -|
     | | | | | | |
     MUX MUX MUX AND--NOT-- Select bit 0
     |  -|---|   |        |
     | | |  -|---+         - To all MUX on first stage
     | | | | |   | 
     | | | | |   | 
     MUX MUX AND AND--NOT-- Select bit 1
     |   |   |   |        |
     |   |   |   |         - to all MUX on this stage
     |   |   |   |
     AND AND AND AND--NOT-- Select bit 2 (to all AND on this stage)
      |   |   |   |
```

When made bidirectional (not shown:  `n`-bit has `n` muxers on the front and back, reverses the input, then reverses the output), a 32-bit shifter has 16% as many gates, a 64-bit shifter uses 15% as many gates, and a 128-bit shifter uses 13% as many gates (not counting inverters. of which the circuit has `log(n)`).

This can implement `SLLI`, `SRLI`, `SLL`, `SRL`, `SLLIW`, `SRLIW`, `SLLW`, and `SRLW` from the RISC-V RV32I and RV64I specifications, as well as the 128-bit versions when released.

It can't implement `SRAI`, `SRA`, `SRAIW`, or `SRAW`.

The arithmetic shift right works like any other barrel shifter, but extends the sign bit:

```
 bit  4   3   2   1
      |  -|  -|  -|-   --Arithmetic Shift
      | | | | | | | | |
      | | | | | | | AND
      | | | | | | |  |
      | | | | | | |  Sx   Sign-extend bit
      | | | | | | |
      | | | | | | | Sx
      | | | | | | | |
      MUX MUX MUX MUX--Select bit 0 (To all stage-1 MUX)
      |  -|---+   |
      | | |  -|---+
      | | | | |  -|-+---Sx
      | | | | | | | |
      MUX MUX MUX MUX--Select bit 1 (To all stage-2 MUX)
      |   |   |   |
      |  -|-+-|-+-|-+---Sx
      | | | | | | | |
      MUX MUX MUX MUX--Select bit 2 (To all stage-3 MUX)
       |   |   |   |
```

Above, when shifting right (input goes through 4 more MUXes, output goes through 4 more muxes, not shown), the shifted-in MSBs become `0` if not arithmetic or if the MSB is `0`, and `1` if arithmetic *and* the MSB is `1`.  I have found no method for improving on this.

I suppose this is why I couldn't find a barrel shifter schematic that wasn't just all MUXes:  it's just not useful if you need an arithmetic shift.  At 128-bit you add 254 gates; at 64-bit you add 126 gates; at 32-bit you add 62 gates; all to support sign-extension.

Comment: Sorry, did you have question?

Comment: Do you mean that by replacing a few "mux(x,y,0)" with "y&~x" you can significantly reduce synthesised gate count?

Comment: If you are looking into barrel shifter implementations, another way is to have output width double input width, then invert shift count and use either upper or lower output for left or rigth shift. It is sometimes smaller or faster than using muxes on input and output data.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson Yes, there's a question asking if the optimised barrel shifter can be made arithmetic.

Comment: @TEMLIB yeah, for a 128-bit bidirectional non-arithmetic shift you save 510 gates (3,300 instead of 3,840).  Problem is I can't seem to make it sign-extend without adding those 510 gates in, plus at least one AND gate.

Comment: @TEMLIB it's notable my implementation uses two rails per each bit and each gate requires an XOR and an AND gate (A XOR B has to be 1 or it'll read 0 on both rails), so it's space-hungry as it is.  That's out of scope though.

Comment: have you consider using base negative 2? or base negative 3 even.

Comment: Your ASCII diagrams are a little hard to follow. It looks like you are inserting Sx into bit 1 on the right end. Shouldn't it be inserted into bit 3 on the left end? Why are the data bits numbered 1 to 4 while the select bits are numbered 0 to 2? In general, a logical right shift is made into an arithmetic right shift by adding a single mux for the MSB. It's not clear to me why this won't work for you. Maybe if you could draw a real schematic I could see it.

Comment: You might also want to consider that in modern CMOS designs a large multiplexer is constructed using transmission gates or even pass transistors. If you are assuming that a mux is made from logic gates then your comparisons might not be accurate.

Comment: @Elliot Anderson it's kind of easier to construct the left shifter than the right one (the logic to describe it is simpler), and a bidirectional shifter has to reverse the input to shift in the opposite direction either way, so I based from a left shifter.

Comment: @JohnMoser Just noticed this. It looks like a logic shifter, not a barrel shifter, to me. Barrel shifters do rotation and not just a shift. Did you work out an answer?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see shift and rotate.